# Syncing events page with a google calendar

Tags: php, html, css, google-api

I'm building an HTML/CSS website for a musician friend of mine and I want to have his events page sync with his google calendar. Is there some way to grab data from his calendar (date/description/location) and have the system automatically create HTML elements which will then appear on his page?

Additionally, I would like to have events move from an *upcoming gig* section to a *past gig* section after the date has passed. From what I understand, this might be possible using PHP and the Google calendar API. Any advice, however detailed, would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at fullcalendar...I do the very same thing for one of my websites:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/